# Django models with extra details

Tags: django

I am not sure how to structure following:

I have one **Invitation** object, that has many **Recipients** objects (ManyToManyField) attach to it. But I want to add more **Invitation** related data that should not be on the **Recipient** object, but it should relate to single **Recipient**. How would you structure that?

I can see two approaches:

a) Add new model **InvitationExtra** that will have following fields:

- invitation foreign key
- recipient
- extra data

But then I would not be able to use **select_related** method from Django queryset.

b) Add new model **InvitationRecipient** that will be defined as a ManyToManyField on the **Invitation** object and will have following fields:

- recipient
- extra data

Then I could use **prefetch_related** method to get all related fields.

Any suggestion on the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an association class  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!